# Dygraph - highlight area below line only Or multi colour background depend on Y axis value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dygraphs

I am using Dygraph to show students attendance. I am highlighting the area with low attendance in specific month. I am using [this](http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/highlighted-weekends) example from dygraph site.

In this chart, highlighted area is from top to bottom yellow. Is it possible to highlight area below series line only not top to bottom?

Updated -
Is it possible to add multiple background colour according to Y axis value I mean at Y axis value 0 to 30 background will be red , 30 to 60 yellow & 60 to 100 green ?

Comment: I think it is not possible in a easy way. If you realize you could restrict the area as dygraphs use a canvas to highlight it. You could restrict also the top and bottom, but if the shape of the graph is irregular it is going to be a complicated task to create the canvas to colour only the area below. 
So I would say it is not direct, you can not just set a parameter. 
Regards.

Comment: Oh..! Then @LucidioVacas is it possible to add multiple background colour according to Y axis value I mean at Y axis 0 to 30 background will be red , 30 to 60 yellow & 60 to 100 green?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible to add multiple background colour according to Y axis value. Below you have the code necessary and a jsfiddle where you can see how to do it.

```
 function highlightYaxesWithColour(y_start, y_end, color) {
          var canvas_bottom = g.toDomYCoord(y_start);
          var canvas_top = g.toDomYCoord(y_end);
          var canvas_height = canvas_top - canvas_bottom;
          canvas.fillStyle = color;
          canvas.fillRect(area.x, canvas_bottom, area.w, canvas_height);
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lucidio/2rmLLdcm/

Comment: Perfectly work..!! Thanks @Lucidio Vacas ..! You save my day..! I will change question.